# Jquery index can't find element (-1) wrong input (with live function)

Tags: jquery, indexing, live

I like to get the index of the li element. The li elements are created after the page loaded. Jquery returns a -1 not found error.

The structure html (found in dom, not in page source):

```
<div id="warp-expand">
  <ul>
   <li><div class="song"><div class="list_b"></div><a>test1</a></div></li>
   <li><div class="song"><div class="list_b"></div><a>test2</a></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery to get the li index:

```
 $("#warp-expand ul li a").live('click',function () {

    var x = $("warp-expand ul li").index(this);
    alert(x); //returns -1  

 });
```

How the li's are made:

```
 $("#playlister").click(function () {
    $("#jp_playlist_2 ul li").each(function()
    {
    var s = $(this).text();
    $('#warp-expand ul').append('<li><div class="song"><div class="list_b"></div><a>' +s+ '</a></div></li>');
    });

});
```

Comment: You're missing `#warp-expand` for your index function.

Comment: @Scurker: Pls post tht as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('#warp-expand a').live('click',function () {    
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();    
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Aphrq/1/

So, as you can see, calling `index()` without any parameters works just fine. Just select the element (in this case the corresponding LI element) and call `index()` on it.

---

Also, consider caching your DOM element reference on page-load:

```
// cache reference on page-load (do this for all your references)
var warp = $('#warp-expand');

// use delegate(), it's better!
warp.delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();        
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Aphrq/2/

Comment: Also a helpful answer. Thank you for your advice on efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#warp-expand ul li a ").live('click',function () {

    var x = $(this).closest('li').index();
    alert(x); 

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vGsE/