# Get the nth-child param value with a class selector that is equal to "active" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, css-selectors

How do I get the nth-child param value with a class selector that is equal to "active" in jQuery?

I'm not sure if this is logical but I want to determine which of the list of dd elements that I have is currently selected through the nth-param value.

The code is actually a loop of vertical tabs from Foundation's Vertical Tabs.

```
<dl class="vertical tabs">  
<?php foreach($tabs as $key):?>
    <dd id="ver_tab"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajaxFunc('<?php echo ($key['group_name']) ?>')" id="ver_tab_a"><?php echo ucwords($key['group_name']);?></a></dd>        
<?php endforeach ?>
    <dd><a id="new_group_button" href="#new_group_form">+ New Group</a></dd>
```

I have a list of tabs with data acquired dynamically. I also have a static tab at the bottom which would add a new group. A click on a tab from the dynamically generated tab would add a class with value "active" What I want is when I click the static tab, a modal is open and when I cancel the modal(modal is from Foundation's Reveal also), the selected tab should revert to the active tab before I click the static tab.

On my jQuery I have:

```
$("#ver_tab:nth-child("+x+")").attr("class","active");
```

To revert to the previously selected tab where the x is the nth-child of the selected tab.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It would be good to include a sample of your html, and your attempt at the Javascript so we can see where you are going wrong and what exactly you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after a long search.

Although this answer is on different approach, nevertheless it solve my problem on how to identify the index number of my currently selected tab.

Here's what I did.
On my:

```
<dd id="ver_tab"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajaxFunc('<?php echo ($key['group_name']) ?>')" id="ver_tab_a"><?php echo ucwords($key['group_name']);?></a></dd>
```

I added another paramater on the:

```
onclick="('<?php echo ($key['group_name']) ?>')"
```

So it looks like:

```
onclick="('$(this)','<?php echo ($key['group_name']) ?>')"
```

Then on my ajaxFunc:

```
function ajaxFunc(x, group_name){
    var pos = x.closest("dd").index;
}
```

The pos variable should now contain the index value of currently selected tab.

Thanks to this post [Jquery index can't find element (-1) wrong input (with live function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540864/jquery-index-cant-find-element-1-wrong-input-with-live-function?answertab=votes#tab-top)! Save me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the `.active` element:

```
$('dd.active').index('dd')
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if the solution I'm trying to do is the correct one. I'm posting the code above, please refer to the description. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I also have another set of dd(horizontal tab) with one which is currently active. But I think this solution will work if a selector is specified, I haven't tried it though. Sorry if I haven't elaborated it that much. Thanks anyway!